# rsa archer data extract

Tags: data-extraction, archer

When we use any ETL tool to download data using webservices we get the following issues.

1. When there are more fields in a module like 400 then it is becoming tough to extract data using webservices API
2. it is extracting in xml so we need to parse it

Is there any script which can be called to download the data in txt or csv format? Is there any bulk extract method to extract data like 400 fields in a single shot?

Answer (score 2):

***Is there any script which can be called to download the data in txt or csv format?

Is there any bulk extract method to extract data like 400 fields in a single shot?***
Short answer is no.

But you have two options here:
Option 1. You can write a code that will extract data via Archer API page by page and convert this data into the format that your ETL tool can integrate with. Initially Archer will return data in XML as you described, but this can be changed by your custom code.
Note - for example Informatica (ETL Tool) allows you embed Java and C# code into the ETL workflow, so you can extract all the data you need by ETL tool right away. Configuration (report ID in Archer) can be stored in a file, so this solution should be easy to support in the long run.
Option 2: If you have read access to Archer database you may create a SQL statement that will extract data directly from the database. this is a complex solution, because for each field you want to extract you will have to "JOIN" multiple tables based on the field type.Just to extract data from one text field you will have to do 5 JOINS. Complexity is higher for Value Lists and Cross-References and Related Records.
Also you have to remember that your SQL statement will have to be updated every time the field name of field type is changed. So it is harder to support.
Archer to ETL, and Archer to BI tools integration is an interesting topic.
Good luck!